# Understanding definition of n-dimensional moment generating function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

[image]

I don't understand, why is the moment generating function not defined for some values? What values could these be?

Also, how big are those intervals $(-c_i,c_i)$ . Are they supposed to be arbitrary small and close to $0$?

Comment: Do you know the answer to this question in the one-dimensional case?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy actually no

Comment: There are random variables whose MGF is only defined at $0$ itself; it's not the case that the MGF is defined in a neighbourhood of zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the 1-dimensional case. If $X$ has $exp(1)$ distribution then $Ee^{tX}=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} e^{tx}dx$ which is $\infty$ for $t \geq 1$. Many standard distributions have infinite MGF outside some interval around $0$.